# A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller 'Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am getting the below error in logs.

```
A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller 'Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController.
```

I am using Sitecore Form OOTB save action method. There is no issue on front end but still seeing this error in logs.

Comment: Which Sitecore version? Is it an upgrade scenario? Do you have forms extensions module installed? Is it a new exception or was it like that in the past?

Comment: Sitecore 10.0 Version. its not upgrade scenario. Forms extension module not installed. Its new exception.

Comment: If it's a new exception that means you (or someone in your team) changed something. Track all the changes related to dependency injection and forms to find out what's the reason.

Comment: Does your form load and work correctly in the front-end and you only see this error message in Sitecore logs?

Comment: yes form work correctly in front end and seeing this error only in logs.

Comment: Open the /sitecore/layout/Renderings/System/Forms/Mvc Form item and check its Controller field to the following value:
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc

also check are you using this rendering on presentation

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have any problems with Sitecore Forms on the website, the most likely reason for these error messages is requests made to this page using HTTP methods other than `GET`, `HEAD` or `POST`.

The method `Index` of controller `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController` supports only `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST` requests:

```
namespace Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers
{
  public class FormBuilderController : BaseFormBuilderController
  {
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
    [SetFormMode(Editing = false)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateFormRequest]
    public ActionResult Index(FormDataModel data)
    {
      ...
    }

  }
}
```

So if your page with a Sitecore form receives another HTTP request method (for example, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `PATCH`, `OPTIONS`, etc), then `FormBuilderController` will throw this exception because it can't find the `Index` method allowed for this HTTP verb. It can happen during security scans or, for example, if a bot sends requests with uncommon HTTP verbs.

Therefore, this error does not necessarily mean that there is a problem with forms. Sitecore have previously fixed the error for `HEAD` requests (see [this patch for 9.0.2](https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.294567/releases)), but it can still appear for other HTTP verbs.